# No funciona datediff con week en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando obtener el número de semanas en MySQL, pero al utilizar la función `datediff` con `week` no funciona:

```sql
SELECT ds_publicId,dt_start_date,dt_end_date,
DATEDIFF(week,dt_start_date,dt_end_date) AS 'semana'
FROM upl_academicperiods
WHERE ds_publicId = 2220
```

Comment: Qué error te sale? El `DATEDIFF` solo recibe dos parámetros, el de inicio y fin. En T-SQL si recibe tres.

Comment: Prueba con `timestampdiff(week,dt_start_date,dt_end_date)`.